# Python/Pandas - How to Write Results of pd.crosstabs() to Text File

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to write results of pd.crosstabs to a text file in Python 3.11.1. I have tried two approaches with no luck.

Code 1

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

df01 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],'col2':['C','C','D','C','C','C','D','C']})

with open('FreqReport.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Date: "+str(today))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("Number of Widgets by Day")
    f.write("\n")
    pd.crosstab(index=df01['col1'], columns=df01['col2'])
```

Code 2

```
freq1 = pd.crosstab(index=df01['col1'], columns=df01['col2'])
freq1.shape

with open('FreqReport.txt', type) as f:
    f.write("Date: "+str(today))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("Number of Wigets by Day")
    f.write("\n")
    for i in range(len(freq1)):
        f.write(str(freq1.iloc[i,:]))
```

Neither of these work. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f.write(str(pd.crosstab(index=df01['col1'], columns=df01['col2'])))